# Event ID 3: Error "/ProfileService.svc does not exist." (AD Profile Import)

Tags: sharepoint-2013, profile, endpoint, ups, synchronization

I know this is a common Issue. It can be solved when restarting managed metadata service, UserProfile service and UserProfileSync service. (So SharePoint can recreate the endpoint listener in IIS)

*WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/8465037
 Exception: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The service '/94af0fd5ed3c4bfbba3db7dd7cc66fbc/ProfileService.svc' does not exist. ---> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: The service '/94af0fd5ed3c4bfbba3db7dd7cc66fbc/ProfileService.svc' does not exist.
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 17764*

But in our case (SharePoint 2013, SP1) we only have UserProfile Service activated for AD Import. We dont need the Synchronisation Service be active. So i cant resolve this Problem the "normal" way.

**My UP listeners are follow:**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $upa.Endpoints|%{Write-Host $_.ListenUris;}
```

http://xxxx:32843/94af0fd5ed3c4bfbba3db7dd7cc66fbc/ProfileService.svc
https://xxxx:32844/94af0fd5ed3c4bfbba3db7dd7cc66fbc/ProfileService.svc

The root cause of the Problem is as we know, the missing "ProfileService.svc" File in the WebService IIS Root folder. But this file is only created when UPS is active. So how do i resolve this Error in my environment? How do i remove these endpoints for a good? Any suggestions?

Thanks very much for any reply!

Kind regards,

SharePoint_Dude

Answer (score 0):

In IIS

Sites > SharePoint Web Services > "select UPS ID"

on the bottom click 'content View'
ProfileService.svc is missing

So click explore or open C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\WebServices\Profile"

Copy one of the existing svc files and rename to ProfileService.svc

Replace content with

`<%@ServiceHost 
  Language="c#"

Service="Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyService, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
  Factory="Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
%>`

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/c6a10eba-d1cf-41a0-b45d-576a039b731e/the-service-profileservicesvc-does-not-exist?forum=sharepointgeneral